# How should this Untagged question be categorized

Tags: discussion

Shouldn't  [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17359/moving-from-release-candidate-to-release-without-rebuilding-the-package) be moved to SO where a "release" tag exists or if not, how can this untagged question be categorized?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple issues with this, so I'll address them one at a time.

### **Should it go to SO?**

- No, because SO is for questions specifically about programming.

### **Should it go to Programmers**

- Quite possibly, because it certainly has to do with software engineering.

### Does it belong here

- Personally, I feel that questions about the general SDLC should be allowed here. However, I don't recall if this has been addressed on meta. A quick search didn't yield anything, but I fully admit I could have searched harder.

### How should it be tagged?

- If we decide that SDLC questions should be allowed here, then it should be tagged with a new tag, SDLC. If we decide they shouldn't, then we shouldn't tag it - I would then migrate it to programmers.

Comment: SO is about programming and Programmers is about s/w engineering? Hmm ok. I thought Programmers is to do with concepts about s/w development only. But the thing is this question talks about a release candidate. I've seen questions about release candidate and SDLC on SO.

Comment: @ilm you may have seen them (there are in fact more on SO than on Programmers), but they shouldn't be there. In 99% of cases, if you don't have code, it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: I as well like the SDLC questions. By QAing the process we make QAing the code far easier.